# Hide/show column in data table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have data table which have 10 column(th). 5th column header and value should show only if $userRole === 'Admin'.

I am able to do this while creating table header by giving condition in php(if ($userRole === 'Admin')),so if $userRole is Admin then only this column header will display otherwise it won't display.

Same thing i need in column filed also in jquery(in data table),if $userRole === 'Admin' then only { "data": "course_exam_status" } should display.how to handle this in data table not sure.

conclusion:5th column  (Pending Score) with column value({ "data": "course_exam_status" }) should display only if $userRole === 'Admin',for other role this 5th header and role there should not be display .

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        table = $('#data_listing').DataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            paging: true,
            searching: false,
            processing: false,
            bLengthChange: false,
            aaSorting: [],
        aoColumnDefs: [{
                'bSortable': false,
                'aTargets': [-1,0,2, 4]
            }],
            ajax: {
                url: "/training/course",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                dataSrc: function(result) {
                    if (result.data != "") {
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                            result.data[i].subdomain = creating_action(result.data[i]);
                            if (result.data[i].roleName === "Admin") {
                                result.data[i].course_name = creating_checkbox(result.data[i]);
                           }
                        }
                    }
                   
                    return result.data;
                },
            
            },
            columns: [{
                    "data": "course_name"
                },
                {
                    "data": "instructorName"
                },
                {
                    "data": "organization_name"
                },
                {
                    "data": "timezone"
                },
                {
                    "data": "course_exam_status"
                },
                {
                    "data": "startdate"
                },
                {
                    "data": "status"
                },
                {
                    "data": "isimported"
                },
                {
                    "data": "studentcount"
                },
                {
                    "data": "subdomain"
                }
            ]
        });
```

```html
 <table id="data_listing" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead class="theader">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">class Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Training Center</th>
                    <th scope="col">Time Zone</th>
                    <?php if ($userRole === 'Admin') { ?>
                    <th scope="col">Pending Score</th>
                     <?php } ?>
                    <th scope="col">Start Date & Time</th>
                    <th scope="col">Status</th>
                    <th scope="col"> ype</th>
                    <th scope="col">Count</th>
                    <th scope="col">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

Comment: on init you can set columndefs, look in the man https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html. other possibility would be to set a certain class for the 5th column and depending on the role, set the visibility to none or block

Comment: @FatFreddy have tried with columndefs but this also did not work for me,not geeting what wrong i am doing...columnDefs: [

            {

                "targets": [ 4 ],

                "visible": false,

                "searchable": false

            },]